# Google Apps Script - Server Side Authentication

Tags: google-apps-script

I would like to use GAS script as some sort of a web service. Basically, I would like to post some parameters and then using Drive service do some manipulations of Google Doc and all of this has to be done from backend, without use of browser. Now I have issue with authentication - When I deploy GAS as a Web App (Execute the app as user accessing the app, Anyone can access app), when trying to execute script via Http request, I get Google Login response (/accounts/ServiceLogin). Obviously user has to authenticate access. I was not able to find if we can apply OAtuh at that point. So my question is - What can be done to achieve this? Is there any mechanism that can be used to atuhenticate to GAS from a server side? Or am I forced to use browser with GAS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could have your own authentication check in the Apps Script code.  You would have NO security settings with the publishing, but implement your own password check in the Apps Script code.  You would set the publish "*Execute the app as*:" setting to **ME**, and the setting of "*Who has access to the app*:" to **Anyone, even anonymous**.  That allows the app to be run by anyone with no authentication.  Then create your own authentication by passing a password in the URL search string.

Even though putting a password in the URL search string is encrypted over a HTTPS connection, it's still considered "bad practice", because the search string could be stored in plain text in the browser history.  But you aren't going to use a browser.

So, your Apps Script App would read a search string parameter from the URL, and either allow the script to be run or not.  You would be implementing your own authentication system.
But you need to evaluate and decide what the security is on your server, or whatever server is sending the request.  If you can send a HTTPS request to an Apps Script with a password in the URL search string, and it's not a security concern on your server, or whatever server is sending the HTTPS request, then you can consider that and make your decision.

If you want to get a response back from Apps Script to your server without anything opening up in the browser, use the Content Service:

[Google Documentation - Content Service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/content/)